# Access nested JSON with unknown keys?

Tags: json, ansible, home-assistant

I have the following json data:

```json
{"results":
{"xxxxxx":{"id":"as23","status":1,"res":"xsd"},
{"xxxxxx":{"id":"fds34","status":2,"res":"dox"},
{"xxxxxx":{"id":"as23","status":1,"res":"kog"},
{"xxxxxx":{"id":"dgs5","status":2,"res":"dox"},
{"xxxxxx":{"id":"as23","status":2,"res":"dox"},
{"xxxxxx":{"id":"as23","status":1,"res":"dox"}
```

The list is very long, but you get the idea. What I want, is to look up for every object containing the id `as23`, and count how many of them have the status `1`.

So, I am using this in HomeAssistant as a rest sensor, and my filter expression looks like this:

```
{{ value_json.results|selectattr("id", "==", "as23")|selectattr("status", "eq", 1)|list|length }}
```

My issue is: I don't know what the value of `xxxxxx` are, and they can differ, and still contain the id `as23`.
How to achieve this?

Comment: What you are proving here is not a valid JSON, are you sure you cannot have a value as multiple objects like that without having an array. Please provide a real [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building up on @β.εηοιτ.βε's answer, this can be achieved without `json_query` (in case you don't want to / can't `pip install jmespath`) using only core functions.

Using the same assumed correct json structure as in @β.εηοιτ.βε's answer, the following task:

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ 
          value_json.results | 
          map('dict2items') | 
          map('map', attribute='value') |
          flatten |
          selectattr('id', '==', 'as23') |
          selectattr('status', '==', 1)
        }}"
```

Gives:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": "as23",
            "res": "xsd",
            "status": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "as23",
            "res": "kog",
            "status": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "as23",
            "res": "dox",
            "status": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a correct version of your JSON that would be:

```json
{
   "results":[
      {
         "xxxxxx":{
            "id":"as23",
            "status":1,
            "res":"xsd"
         }
      },
      {
         "xxxxxx":{
            "id":"fds34",
            "status":2,
            "res":"dox"
         }
      },
      {
         "xxxxxx":{
            "id":"as23",
            "status":1,
            "res":"kog"
         }
      },
      {
         "xxxxxx":{
            "id":"dgs5",
            "status":2,
            "res":"dox"
         }
      },
      {
         "xxxxxx":{
            "id":"as23",
            "status":2,
            "res":"dox"
         }
      },
      {
         "xxxxxx":{
            "id":"as23",
            "status":1,
            "res":"dox"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Your requirement can be easily achieved with the help of the filter [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries) and the [JMESPath query language](https://jmespath.org), that help you achieve wildcards on properties.

Given the debug task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: >-
      value_json | json_query(
        'length(results[].*[] | [?id == `as23` && status == `1`])'
      )
```

This would yield the expected:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  ? |-
    value_json | json_query(
      'length(results[].*[] | [?id == `as23` && status == `1`])'
    )
  : '3'
```